# unable to resize UIImagePickerController more than a certain height

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to incorporate UIImagePickerController into my app by adding it through subview. But somehow I am unable to increase its height beyond a certain fixed size(the size in default camera app). Is there a way to increase the height? Like the "Fast camera" app does it.

Here is my code:

```
    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    [self.picker.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 444)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.picker.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

use [cameraOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) property UIImagePickerController class for custom view

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply
I have already tried that. But in that even setting a frame was tough. I have to customize the camera completely thats why I added it as a subview. Res everthing is fine except for I am not able to increase its height beyond the default camera limit. I can decrease it though. But unable tp increase it.

Comment: try using custom view and set self.picker.cameraOverlayView.frame equal to frame of custom view. apple has provided nice example for the same. It might help you, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/PhotoPicker_APLViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196-PhotoPicker_APLViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

Answer (score 0):

i don't know it exactly you want like.

try this one:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
self.picker.delegate = self;
[self.picker.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.picker.view];
```

i checked it working good in my app.

Happy Coding...